# Integration of Fcm with angular 17 Module '"@angular/fire/messaging"' has no exported member 'AngularFireMessaging'

Tags: javascript, angular, angularfire, angular17

Hi everyone iam tring to integrate fcm to angular 17 - standalone project using angularfire 17.0.1
import { AngularFireMessaging } from '@angular/fire/messaging';
when iam trying too request using this Module '"@angular/fire/messaging"' has no exported member 'AngularFireMess

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^17.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^17.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
```

> App.config.ts

```
import { getFirestore, provideFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import {
  ApplicationConfig,
  isDevMode,
  importProvidersFrom,
} from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideServiceWorker } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getMessaging, provideMessaging } from '@angular/fire/messaging';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideServiceWorker('ngsw-worker.js', {
      enabled: !isDevMode(),
      registrationStrategy: 'registerWhenStable:30000',
    }),
    importProvidersFrom(
      provideFirebaseApp(() =>
        initializeApp({
          projectId: 'fcm-sample-angular',
          appId: '1:1046462604051:web:0d5617d33eaa539e3470e6',
          storageBucket: 'fcm-sample-angular.appspot.com',
          apiKey: 'AIzaSyAgmv9SgWL-lXKiTY9lFw6b1drGwzttdDM',
          authDomain: 'fcm-sample-angular.firebaseapp.com',
          messagingSenderId: '1046462604051',
          measurementId: 'G-BNNWXP8NK5',
        })
      )
    ),
    importProvidersFrom(provideMessaging(() => getMessaging()),    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),),
    
  ],
};
```

Iam trying to integrate fcm on angular 17 using angular fire